# How to know which frame is selected in Carousel component?

Tags: html, google-web-designer

In Google Web Designer, I've added a carousel control. How can I know which image the user is currently viewing?

I added a new `Frame Activated` event, and created a custom action:

```
<script type="text/javascript" gwd-events="handlers">
    window.gwd = window.gwd || {};
    gwd.boardSelectionChanged = function(event) {
      // which frame is showing now?
    };
</script>
```

I need to know the current frame id.

Comment: Hey OP, in order to give some really specific code examples it would be helpful to see the markup of the GWD generated carousel.  I think yu can preview your page, and then if you right-click the carousel and 'view source' you can copy and paste the html in your OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current frame index using the following example:

```
var gallery = document.getElementById('gwd-carouselgallery_1');
console.log(gallery.currentIndex);
```

`'gwd-carouselgallery_1'` is the ID of the carousel.